# Permanecer na mesma aba depois de refresh usando bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, atualização, aba

Bom, eu estou usando Abas com bootstrap, porem sempre que eu dou um refresh para buscar informações nesta aba, ela alterna para a primeira, saindo da 3 ABA, alguem sabe como resolver isso com Botstrap ?

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba">ABA</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba1">ABA 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aba2">ABA 2</a></li>
   </ul>
```

as Divs

```
<div class="tab-content">
 <div id="aba" class="tab-pane fade in active">ABA</div>
 <div id="aba1" class="tab-pane fade in active">ABA 1</div>
 <div id="aba2" class="tab-pane fade in active">ABA 2</div>
</div>
```

Eu tenho um botão na Aba 2 e qdo clico nele para ele buscar informações, ele volta para a primeira, alguem tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso em Bootstrap ?

Comment: Está utilizando alguma linguagem de programação? ou apenas html e css?

Comment: Para o desenvolvimento das Abas, só o bootstrap mesmo colega

Comment: Achei um Script que nãod eixa trocar, 
<script>
$('ul.nav-tabs li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$('ul.nav-tabs > li > a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
    var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
    window.location.hash = id;
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
$('ul.nav-tabs li a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
</script>